# I want to change bottom layer of text field color when i start typing to blue

Tags: ios, swift, viewdidlayoutsubviews

```
func designTextField()
    {
        //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
        nameLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfName.bounds.size.height-1, width: self.tfName.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
        nameLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        tfName.layer.addSublayer(nameLayer)

        //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
        phoneLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfPhone.bounds.size.height-1, width: self.tfPhone.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
        phoneLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        tfPhone.layer.addSublayer(phoneLayer)

        //Set the horizontal line in bottom of text field
        emailLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.tfEmail.bounds.size.height-1, width: self.tfEmail.bounds.size.width, height: 1)
        emailLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        tfEmail.layer.addSublayer(emailLayer)
    }
```

When to use this function to show in the View :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        //Text Field Design
        self.designTextField()

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

Output : [image: When to hit textFieldDidBeginEditing]

Bottom layer background color will change to blue, when to hit the "Name" text field. But when i type some characters in the text field, then the text field bottom color will change to lightgray(but when i typing then the bottom layer will be same to blue.)

Output : [image: When i start typing]

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        if textField == self.tfName
        {
            nameLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 174/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            imgName = UIImage(named: "user2")!
            imgVwName.image = imgName
            tfName.leftView = imgVwName
        }
        else if textField == self.tfPhone
        {
            phoneLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 174/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            imgPhone = UIImage(named: "phone2")!
            imgVwPhone.image = imgPhone
            tfPhone.leftView = imgVwPhone
        }
        else if textField == self.tfEmail
        {
            emailLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 11/255, green: 174/255, blue: 250/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
            imgEmail = UIImage(named: "mail2")!
            imgVwEmail.image = imgEmail
            tfEmail.leftView = imgVwEmail
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
    {
        if textField == self.tfName
        {
            nameLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            imgName = UIImage(named: "user1")!
            imgVwName.image = imgName
            tfName.leftView = imgVwName
        }
        else if textField == self.tfPhone
        {
            phoneLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            imgPhone = UIImage(named: "phone1")!
            imgVwPhone.image = imgPhone
            tfPhone.leftView = imgVwPhone
        }
        else if textField == self.tfEmail
        {
            emailLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
            imgEmail = UIImage(named: "mail1")!
            imgVwEmail.image = imgEmail
            tfEmail.leftView = imgVwEmail
        }
    }
```

Can somebody plzz help ???

Comment: are these the all related code? Are you sure you are not changing nameLayer anywhere else? Because your code seems ok.

Comment: yes this is all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write in textfield `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called every time and call designTextField (designTextField add a new sublayer with grayColor). You can check if is the first time with a flag, or call designTextField in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, or check if the layer was added.

Comment: Thanks Kevinosaurio

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [SkyFloatingField](https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField) as it is lightweight library which fulfil your requirement.